# Communicating between Flex Project and Customed Library

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Can we access the variables of main project in the customized library or vice-versa ?

Answer (score 0):

The Main project can access the Library project (add it via the Main project's Properties>Flex Build Path>Add SWC), but the library does not access the Main project files directly.

An alternative is to have a third Common library project that contains classes that will be common to both the Main project and the Library project in question.

Comment: Is it possible to have a two way communication between two libraries? (by importing the other library in it)

Comment: Off hand I dont know. Just create two library projects and a main project. Try creating and importing the libraries into each other (probably not though, Im sure there is some Circular Referencing problems with that sort of setup). Best way to find out is to just do up a test project setup